# In Java, how do I flush the CPU memory cache so it retrieves the latest from the RAM memory?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, synchronized

A computer has RAM memory, but it also has small, faster CPU memory cache.
The Java Memory Model guarantees that that CPU memory cache is flushed when accessing a variable with `volatile`, but since we're only using that volatile variable in a single class in a single thread, it's uncertain that JIT doesn't just optimize it away.

To diagnose a bug (which only manifests itself when we call Thread.sleep() long enough at a certain point), we need to be able to do something like this (instead of the sleep()):

```
System.clearCpuCache();
```

**What's the simplest and most reliable way to implement such a method?** It should guarantee that it won't JIT optimize away the cache flush.
We can only reproduce our bug with JIT enabled, so disabling JIT is not an option.

Comment: entering and exiting a `synchronized` block should also work

Comment: I have never heard of the JIT optimizing away volatile writes. Do you have any documentation of that it will do so?

Comment: @Johannes No proof at all, just doubt :)

Comment: You speak about a bug. What are its symptoms ? It is odd to get troubles with volatile, JIT and concurrency troubles when you only use one single thread. If possible please post a testable code with the "sleep" that produces the bug. You probably look in the wrong direction.

Comment: What do you mean by "flush the store buffer" in your bounty comment ? Have you chosen relevant words ? Please provide details and piece of code

Comment: @YvesMartin There was a bug in our code and we wanted to exclude the possibility that it was caused by a stale CPU cache. So someone proposed to just access a `volatile` field in that part of the code to exclude that possibility. But we were uncertain whether or not that volatile field wouldn't be optimized away by the JIT compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You generally cannot. Except for performance, the existence of the cache is transparent to applications. This applies to multiprocessor systems as well, as long as the cache system is "cache-coherent", which is practically all platforms in use today.

Thus, your bug lies elsewhere.

Things like volatile and synchronized blocks don't affect the cache coherency per se, but rather register optimizations, use of atomic instructions (including, say, flushing the store buffer, which is not the same as the cache!), and so on. These are the things you should be looking at (well, given the lack of detail in your description, it's hard to say, but as a first guess..), rather than trying to flush the cache.

Comment: In that case, how does one flush the store buffer reliable?

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet: Depends. On x86, e.g. the "mfence" instruction. In Java, using volatiles, synchronized blocks and such should cause the JVM to issue such instructions as necessary.

Comment: "Volatile variables are not cached in registers or in caches where they are hidden from other processors" - from Concurrency In Practice by Brian Goetz. Or is it different from what you are saying?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov It's saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Access to volatile variable should bypass the cache, not to flush it. So clearing the cache should not affect volatile's behaviour.
How does the bug manifests itself? Do you see stale value after Thread.sleep(), and on the same thread?
Many years ago I wrote tests for the Java Compatibility Test Suite. One of that test proved that volatile variable can be read from cache, not from main memory. I wonder if that bug still exists. Please send me details to rfq(at)list.ru, I'll try to create convincing test.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the case here (more detail required!), but one thing to be aware of if you're seeing a hard threading bug around volatile is that volatile is not necessarily atomic.

i.e. you may think you've updated a volatile variable and that the new value should be visible, but in fact you have't because the full update hasn't completed.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp11234/

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with an [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) ?

I can't see how you can get the wrong version of a volatile int from the cpu cache if the value is always changed/read by the same thread. Maybe try to print out which thread is active on each read/write on the variable, just to be 100% sure:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
```